# To Add New row to dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the below code i have dynamic table with dynamic colmnns.I can able to generate table now i want to add new row .As this dynamic table has dynamic id's for each textbox/dropdown/checkbox of the table.So when i click new row it also have dynamic id for each textbox/dropdown/checkbox.Pls help me to do this.

```
function LoadTableFields(sFieldID, Name, newdiv, FieldValue, TableValues) {

    var TblValues = JSON.parse(TableValues);
    var tHTML = '';
    tHTML += '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="table_' + sFieldID + '" name="' + Name + '"><thead><tr >';
    var headers = [];
    $.each(TblValues, function(i, item) {
        if (headers.indexOf(item.Name) === -1) {
            headers.push(item.Name);
            tHTML += '<th class="text-center">' + item.Name + '</th>';
        }
    });
    tHTML += '</tr></thead><tbody><tr id="row_0" data-id="0">';
    var Count = 0;
    $.each(TblValues, function(i, item) {

        if (item.FieldType == 'TextBox') {
            if (item.Name === headers[0]) {
                tHTML += '<tr>';
            }
            tHTML += '<td data-name=' + item.Name + ' class="col-xs-3 form-group"><input type="text" id=' + item.Name + i + '     name=' + item.Name + i + ' placeholder=' + item.Name + ' class="form-control" value=' + item.FieldValue + ' /></td>';

            if (item.Name === headers[headers.length - 1]) {
                tHTML += '</tr>';
            }
        } else if (item.FieldType == 'DropDownList') {
            if (item.Name === headers[0]) {
                tHTML += '<tr>';
            }
            var options = LoadTableFieldEnums(sFieldID, item.Name, item.FieldValue);
            tHTML += '<td data-name=' + item.Name + ' class="col-xs-3 form-group"><select id=' + item.Name + i + ' name=' + item.Name + i + ' class="form-control">' + options + '</select></td>';
            if (item.Name === headers[headers.length - 1]) {
                tHTML += '</tr>';
            }

        } else if (item.FieldType == 'CheckBox') {
            tHTML += '<td data-name=' + item.Name + '><input type="checkbox" id=' + item.Name + i + ' name=' + item.Name + i + '/></td>';
        } else if (item.FieldType == 'Date') {
            if (item.Name === headers[0]) {
                tHTML += '<tr>';
            }
            tHTML += '<td data-name=' + item.Name + ' class="col-xs-3 form-group"><div class="input-group date"><input type="text" class="form-control" id=' + item.Name + '0' + ' name=' + item.Name + '0' + ' /><span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span></div></td>';
            if (item.Name === headers[headers.length - 1]) {
                tHTML += '</tr>';
            }
            Count = i;
        } else {
            tHTML += '<td data-name=' + item.Name + '></td>';
        }

    });

    tHTML += '</tr></tbody></table>';
    tHTML += '<a id="add_row_' + sFieldID + '" class="btn btn-default pull-left" onclick="AddNewTableRow(' + sFieldID + ');">Add Row</a><a id="delete_row_' + sFieldID + '" class="pull-right btn btn-default" onclick="DeleteTableRow(' + sFieldID + ');">Delete Row</a>';
    newdiv.innerHTML += tHTML;

    $('#divComplete').append(newdiv);

}



function AddNewTableRow(sFieldID) {
    // Dynamic Rows Code

    // Get max row id and set new id
    var newid = 0;
    $.each($("#table_" + sFieldID + " tr"), function() {
        if (parseInt($(this).data("id")) > newid) {
            newid = parseInt($(this).data("id"));
        }
    });
    newid++;

    var tr = $("<tr></tr>", {
        id: "row_" + newid,
        "data-id": newid
    });

    // loop through each td and create new elements with name of newid
    $.each($("#table_" + sFieldID + " tbody tr:nth(0) td"), function() {
        var cur_td = $(this);

        var children = cur_td.children();

        // add new td and element if it has a nane
        if ($(this).data("name") != undefined) {
            var td = $("<td></td>", {
                "data-name": $(cur_td).data("name")
            });

            // Date control
            if ($(children[0]).prop('tagName') == 'DIV') {
                var strname = $(cur_td).data("name");
                var c = $('<div class="input-group date"><input type="text" class="form-control" id=' + strname + '' + newid + ' name=' + strname + '' + newid + ' /><span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span></div>');
                c.appendTo($(td));
            } else {
                var c = $(cur_td).find($(children[0]).prop('tagName')).clone().val("");
                c.attr("name", $(cur_td).data("name") + newid);
                c.attr("id", $(cur_td).data("name") + newid);
                c.appendTo($(td));
            }
            td.appendTo($(tr));
        } else {
            var td = $("<td></td>", {
                'text': $('#table_' + sFieldID + ' tr').length
            }).appendTo($(tr));
        }
    });

    // add the new row
    $(tr).appendTo($('#table_' + sFieldID));
}

function DeleteTableRow(sFieldID) {
    var newid = 0;
    $.each($("#table_" + sFieldID + " tr"), function() {
        if (parseInt($(this).data("id")) > newid) {
            newid = parseInt($(this).data("id"));
        }
    });

    if (newid != 0) {
        $("#row_" + (newid)).remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you make [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) of your code?